# Turning off the WebFormViewEngine when using razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, webforms, razor

I downloaded [Glimpse](http://www.getglimpse.com/) this morning to try it out and noticed this when I click on the views tab:

[image: Glimpse Views Tab]

It checks all of the loaded view engines.  I found where the `RazorViewEngine` is specified in web.config, but I couldn't find where the `WebFormViewEngine` was.  Since I know my project will never have an web form view in it,

1. Is it ok/safe to turn off `WebFormViewEngine`?
2. How can I turn off `WebFormViewEngine`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It is perfectly OK to remove the web forms view engine if you are not using it. You can do it like:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public void Application_Start()
    {
        // Clears all previously registered view engines.
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

        // Registers our Razor C# specific view engine.
        // This can also be registered using dependency injection through the new IDependencyResolver interface.
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
    }
}
```

The above method calls go in your `global.asax` file.

source of [code](http://web.archive.org/web/20110217183120/http://www.waynehaffenden.com/Blog/ASPNET-MVC-3-Razor-CSharp-View-Engine)

Comment: Your code says that the view engine can also be defined using dependency injection. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: this will search for `.vbhtml` to remove that , use **Custom Razor View Engine**  check [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/NcJP200113-Custom-Razor-View-Engine-for-C#-and-VB.html)

Comment: @stom: An easier way to ignore `.vbhtml` files would be to simply limit the file extensions of the `RazorViewEngine`, for example: `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine { FileExtensions = new [] { "cshtml" } });`

Answer (score 15):

An alternative would be to remove only the view engine you want to remove:

```
    var webformVE = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<WebFormViewEngine>().FirstOrDefault();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(webformVE);
```

Comment: Ran this method against the accepted answer for 3 rounds. They both cost ~4ms for each run (for those who are curious).